# jQuery methods Vs jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was recently assigned a very small but complex task in jQuery, the requirement was quite simple, given the following HTML :

```
<div> 
   <span id="myid2151511" class="myclass23462362">....foobar....</span>
   <span id="myid2151512" class="myclass23462362">....YoLO....</span>
   <span id="myid2151513" class="myclass23462362">....lalal....</span>
   <span id="myid2151514" class="myclass23462362">....foobar....</span>
</div>
```

What i have to do i recursively go through all the span under `div`, With a certain id and check if the values contained in the spans is `foobar`, So i can up with the following jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
     $('div [id^="myid"]:contains("foobar"):last').css({'background' : 'rgb(227, 216, 22)' })
});
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/domrycq6/1/)**

Its quite a complex bit of code by itself, but the jQuery documentation made it a cakewalk for me as for as understanding the code is concerned.

By now i am comfortable writing code like so in jQuery:

```
$('some-Element').somemethod().anothermethod().yetanothermethod();
```

Every function returns a value in the above jQuery statement, so chain ability becomes a reality.

but when i see code like so.

```
$('div [id^="myid"]:contains("foobar"):last').css({'background' : 'rgb(227, 216, 22)' });
```

I am thrown a bit off the hook(although i managed to write the above line myself), notice how alot of the filtering is done by a selector `:last` and `:contains`, to me they appear to be working much like some kind of a jQuery method. So my question is, how do these selectors in jQuery work in comparison to jQuery methods ?

If anybody could explain or give me a vague idea, it would be Fantastic.

**EDIT** ::

well to clarify my question in one line, to me `$(".someClass").eq('10');` makes sense, but somehow `$(".someClass:eq(10)")` does't , i mean it works, but how on earth is it implemented internally ?(I wrote this edit after reading the answers below, and well this question has been thoroughly answered by now, but this edit is just to clarify my question.).

Comment: Do you realize that for selectors jQuery uses the CSS3 selector syntax (with a few extensions of its own added in)?  So, the core syntax is not something jQuery invented.

Comment: When you ask "how to these selectors in jQuery work in comparison to jQuery methods", it's hard to figure out what kind of answer you want or what you're really asking.  Perhaps you could clarify your question.  Here's an article that explains the overall CSS3 selector syntax: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200601/css_3_selectors_explained/

Comment: @jfriend00 , Thanks for bringing this critical point to my notice, and no i was't aware of this.  you partially answered my question .

Comment: @jfriend00 haha thanks , but no i did't want such a basic answer about "how css-3 selectors work" , rather "how jQuery utilizes css-3 selectors" would be more of use to me , even if the difference if meager .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik jQuery use `document.querySelectorAll()` method whenever possible, otherwise it use js selector engine `sizzle`. Not sure it is your question

Comment: Why do this  `[id^="myid"]` when you can do `#myid` and if you have the `id` that's all you need to target the element (ids must be unique per document)

Comment: jQuery just parses the selectors and then matches them to the DOM.  There really is no direct comparison to methods.  In some cases, you can find a method that implements something that can also be found in the CSS3 syntax, but in many other cases methods do things that are not part of the selector syntax at all.  I still can't figure out what you're looking for in an answer.  For example, these would give the same results: `$("#header").find(".subhead")` and `$("#header .subhead")`, but there's no selector operation for a method like `.toggleClass()` as they are just different things.

Comment: @jfriend00 ,  jQuery methods are meant to do most of the heavy lifting , what you stated in your last comment is something , that i believe is overly obvious , my question is pertaining to the scenarios where a selector can or is used to do the job of a jQuery method. I never said a selector is a replacement for a jQuery method, so just because my question is titled "jQuery selectors vs jQuery methods",  does't mean that selectors substitute methods. If you read the question carefully , you'll see i have asked a contextual question , Which should make your job easier to answer.  Thanks .

Comment: I was just trying to make sense of your question and help.  Next time please give exact examples of what you wanted to compare (one version with selector, one with method which apparently you did finally add in an edit much after I was involved).  That would make it much, much easier for people to offer on-target answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, yes nikhil was right. ID is unique identifier and can be only used once. If you are willing to apply same styles to several elements, or you to use it to select several elements together use class attribute. But however, i couldn't understand your question. But maybe this could help

there is function in javascript which is widely supported by almost all major browsers

```
document.querySelectorAll("div [id^=myId]");
```

in fact you could write your own library (well not as advanced one like jquery but)

```
var $ = function(selector){
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}

// and then you could use it like this
var elementsWithMyId = $("div [id^=myId]");
// where elementsWithMyId will contain array of all divs which's id start with myId
```

so as i understood your question, No. there is no magic happening behind jQuery selections it's just browser built in function which is kinda shortened by jquery. of course they added tons of new features, which would work like this:

```
var $ = function(selector){
    var elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    elementsArray.makeBlue = function(){
         for(var i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++){
             elementsArray[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
         }
         // so elementsArray will now have function to make all of its
         // div blues. but if you want to have chain like that, we have to return this array not just make all of it blue
        return elementsArray;
    }

    elementsArray.makeRed = function(){
         for(var i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++){
             elementsArray[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
         }
        return elementsArray;
    }

    return elementsArray;
}

// so now you can use it like this

// this returns array which has options make blue, and make red so lets use make blue first
// makeBlue then returns itself, meaning it returns array which has again options of making itself red and blue so we can use makeRed now
$("div [id^=myId]").makeBlue().makeRed();
```

and thats it!

Comment: Fantastic ! thats what i wanted to know

Answer (score 4):

That's an interesting question. The short answer is they both accomplish the same thing. Of course though, there's always more to the story. In general:

```
$('div [id^="myid"]:contains("foobar"):last').css({'background' : 'rgb(227, 216, 22)' });
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$("div").find("[id^='myid']").filter(":contains('foobar')").last().css({'background' : 'rgb(227, 216, 22)' });
```

Most of the time when you call $(), jQuery is calling `document.querySelectorAll()`. This is a browser implemented function that grabs elements based on a selector. That complex string you create is passed to this method and the elements are returned.

Naturally, things implemented by the browser are faster than JavaScript so the less JavaScript and more C++, the better. As a result, your example passing everything as a selector is likely to be faster as it just sends it all to the browser as one call and tells it "do it." Calling `$()`, `contains()`, `last()` on the other hand is going to call `querySelectorAll` multiple times and therefore it will likely be slower since we're doing more JavaScript as opposed to letting the browser do the heavy lifting in one shot. There are exceptions though. JQuery *generally* calls `querySelectorAll`. However, there are times when it doesn't. This is because jQuery extends what `querySelectorAll` is capable of.

For example, if you do something like `$(".someClass:eq(10)")` per the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/jquery-selector-extensions/):

> jQuery has extended the CSS3 selectors with the following selectors. Because these selectors are jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using them cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using these selectors, first select some elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter().

So in that case, while `$(".someClass:eq(10)")` might seem to be faster, in reality `$(".someClass").eq(10)` or `$(".someClass").filter(":eq(10)")` is going to be faster since the first call will be executed as JavaScript code. The latter two will first call `querySelectorAll` to select by class, then only use JavaScript to find the 10th element. When jQuery has to do the selection in pure JavaScript, it does it using the Sizzle engine which is fast, very fast, but not faster than native code in the browser. So again, the short answer is, they're the same thing, the long answer is, it depends. If you're interested in all the extensions that fall into that category, the link to the jQuery documentation I included lists them.

Comment: As a side note, there is no method `$.fn.contains()` but `$.contains()`: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/  and `:contains()` selector isn't a jQuery feature, unlike `:last`. In this case, the fastest 'selector' would be (i guess): `$('div [id^="myid"]:contains("foobar")').last()`, not `$('div [id^="myid"]:contains("foobar"):last')`

Comment: `the less JavaScript and more C++, the better.` , Wow !! could you explain that line please. great answer though !

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks. I corrected the slower example by calling filter.

Comment: @dman2306 I just edited your code because you were missing a space in selector string :)

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik the browser is generally written in a compiled language like C or C++. When you call a method like `document.querySelectorAll` the JavaScript engine runs C++ code that returns the result, since the implementation of this method is built inside the browser. However, when jQuery has to run stuff itself, it's running JavaScript code to do the selection. As a result, the more heavy lifting you let the browser do, the more it's running in C++ (or whatever language it's written in) which is always going to be faster than JavaScript.